# classList toggle(show) doesn't show the dropdown content

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to toggle on the "cart" of my website. When it is clicked,there will be a dropdown block. It works well on my another website and I almost copy its right code but it just doesn't show the dropdown content on this website. Would someone help me explain it?

html:

```js
function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("drop").classList.toggle("show");
   }
```

```css
    div.icon
    {
     top:25px;
     position:absolute;
     right:20px;
     float:left;
     display:inline-block;
     
    }
    div.dropdown
    {
     
        position: absolute;
     background-color:#F1F1F1;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
        height:215px;
        width:400px;
     text-align:center;
        top:30px;
     right:-6px;
     
    }
    
    .dropdown a
    {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:black;
     background-color:#E9E9E9;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     padding:13px 0 13px 0;
     font-size:11px;
    }
    
    .dropdown p
    {
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     width:100%;
     font-size:13.4px;
    }
    .icon .dropdown::after
    {
     content: "";
        position: absolute;
     bottom: 100%;
        right: 7%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #F1F1F1; transparent;
    }
    
    .show
    {
     display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div>  
       <div class="icon">
      <p class="menu-right" style="color:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; cursor:pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color:white;"></i> Cart</p> 
           <div class="dropdown" id="drop">
          <p>Your shopping cart is empty</p>
          <a style="color:black;" href="#">CONTINUE SHOPPING <small>&gt</small></a>
           </div>    
    </div>
```

The above is the html code. The cart is in the icon class. I create a cart div and a dropdown div. When the cart is be clicked, the dropdown block should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `div.dropdown` in your CSS it's overshadowing `.show`: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Use just `.dropdown` instead.

```css
div.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red blue">blue</div>
<!--div would be blue if you change div.red to .red-->
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your inner element has not a event listener.

a way to do that would be

```
function myFunction() {
      this.classList.toggle("show");
 }

document.getElementById("inner").addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

Comment: ahh ok, I didn't see that :c

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your toggle, your CSS is just off. The class `show` is not applying because of `div.dropdown` taking priority. I've modified example below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("inner").classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```css
div.icon {
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 215px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
  right: -6px;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.dropdown p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13.4px;
}

.icon .dropdown::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 7%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #F1F1F1;
  transparent;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
   <div class="icon">
     <p style="color:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; cursor:pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"> Cart</p> 
       <div class="dropdown" id="inner">
         <p>Your shopping cart is empty</p>
         <a style="color:black;" href="#">CONTINUE SHOPPING <small>&gt</small></a>
       </div>      
   </div>
```